# Serialize UL menu items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a drag and drop menu maker (just like wordpress's menu maker feature) with combination of html, jquery & php. PHP I am using to store the menu items into database. I have already built this feature but it has a small bug which needs to be fixed. Let me explain what I have done.  Below is the example Menu HTML structure which is generated using frontend interface.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 1</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 2</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">

        <!-- Sub menu level 1 : starts -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">This is level 1 item 1</a>
                <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
                <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
                <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">

                <!-- Sub menu level 3 : starts -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">This is level 2 item 1</a>
                        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
                        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
                        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">This is level 2 item 2</a>
                        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
                        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
                        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Sub menu level 3 : ends -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">This is level 1 item 2</a>
                <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
                <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
                <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Sub menu level 1 : ends -->

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 3</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 5</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And before submitting the HTML form, I have build a jquery script which assigns the menu IDs automatically to the hidden fields. And the values gets filled as shown below :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 1</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="1">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="0">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="0">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 2</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="2">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="0">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="1">

        <!-- Sub menu level 1 : starts -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">This is level 1 item 1</a>
                <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="5">
                <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="2">
                <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="0">

                <!-- Sub menu level 3 : starts -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">This is level 2 item 1</a>
                        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="7">
                        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="5">
                        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">This is level 2 item 2</a>
                        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="8">
                        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="5">
                        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="1">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Sub menu level 3 : ends -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">This is level 1 item 2</a>
                <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="6">
                <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="2">
                <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="1">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Sub menu level 1 : ends -->

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 3</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="3">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="0">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is parent item 5</a>
        <input type="text" id="link_id" class="link_id" name="link_id[]" value="4">
        <input type="text" id="parent_id" class="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" value="0">
        <input type="text" id="sortorder" class="sortorder" name="sortorder[]" value="3">
    </li>
</ul>
```

So sort explanation is, **link_id** is the auto generated incremental ID for every menu item which starts from 1. **parent_id** is the parent menu ID for every menu item. For very first level, parent ID will be 0. `sortorder` is the sorting order of menu items on its specific menu level starting from 0.

Below is the javascript which auto fills the input values.

```
// Serialize all menu items before submit
function serialize_menu_items(){
    $("ul li").each(function(e){
        this_index = $(this).index();
        parent_index = $(this).parents('li').find(".link_id:first").val();
        if(parent_index === -1 || typeof parent_index == "undefined") { parent_index = 0; }

        $(this).find(".parent_link_id:first").val(parent_index);
        $(this).find(".sortorder:first").val(this_index);
    });
}
```

Issue is, this script is generating duplicate link_id sometimes. So looking for a fix to this.

Comment: I can not see any class name like `link_id`, `parent_link_id` or `sortorder`

Comment: where is the duplicate link_ids

Comment: This is just to show how the logic generates the proper IDs but in real it is duplicating sometimes which I am not able to track when exactly it is happening

Comment: also nobody is updating `link_id` in the code

Comment: oh right, that is actually getting generated using drag and drop script.

Comment: so the bug could be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write this script, i know this was longer but it worked tested !

set top url id = main-menu : `ul id= "main-menu"`

then paste this code :

```
function slz() {
var menu = document.getElementById("");


var current = menu;
var past = current;
var nextList = [];
var serialized = false;

var link = 0; // link id
var deep = 0; // deep
var i = 0; // sort order

var j = 0;

while (!serialized) {

    serialized = true;

    for (i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
        link++;
        current.children[i].children[1].value = link;
        current.children[i].children[2].value = deep;
        current.children[i].children[3].value = i;
        if (current.children[i].children.length > 4) {

            for (j = 4; j < current.children[i].children.length; j++) {

                nextList.push(current.children[i].children[j]);

            }
        }
    }
    if (nextList.length > 0) {

        past = current;
        current = nextList[0];
        nextList.splice(0, 1);

        if (past.parentNode != current.parentNode) {
            deep++;
        }

        serialized = false;
    }


}

}
slz();
```